# 2 Javascript functions into 1 Form Input Box

Tags: javascript

HEAVILY EDITED:

I have a form which has this input field:

```
<input id="RR_No" type="text" size="15" name="RR_No" readonly></div></TD>
```

In that field, I need to put the date in the format: 
DDMMYYYY

And a Serial Number that is 6 numbers long to make a number like this: 
DDMMYYYYABCDEF

Here is the Javascript to make the date:

```
function autoDate () {
    var tDay = new Date();
    var tMonth = tDay.getMonth()+1;
    var tDate = tDay.getDate();
    if ( tMonth < 10) tMonth = "0"+tMonth;
    if ( tDate < 10) tDate = "0"+tDate;
    document.getElementById("RR_Date").value = tDate+"/"+tMonth+"/"+tDay.getFullYear();
    document.getElementById("RR_No").value = tDate+""+tMonth+""+tDay.getFullYear();
 }

function addLoadEvent(func) {
  var oldonload = window.onload;
  if (typeof window.onload != 'function') {
    window.onload = func;
  } else {
    window.onload = function() {
      if (oldonload) {
        oldonload();
      }
      func();
    }
  }
}

addLoadEvent(function() {
  autoDate();
});
```

Which works.

I then have this JavaScript that copies the Serial Number into the same Input box:

```
$(function(){
    $("#copyCheck").change(function() {
        if ($("#copyCheck:checked").length > 0) {
            bindGroups();
        } else {
            unbindGroups();
        }
    });
});

var bindGroups = function() {
    // First copy values
    $("input[name='RR_No']").val($("input[name='S_Serial_No']").val());

    // Then bind fields
    $("input[name='S_Serial_No']").keyup(function() {
        $("input[name='RR_S_No']").val($(this).val());
    });
};

var unbindGroups = function() {
    $("input[name='SN_No0']").unbind("keyup");
};
```

But this second code overwrites the date already in the Input box. 
I need it to show beside the Date within the same Input box.

Hope this makes more sense.

Chris

Comment: Wouldn't it be more identifiable if you always knew what the ID was instead of having it be different every time the page loads?

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Is this ID field a 3rd input or is it overwriting one of the two source fields?

Comment: The form submits into a database that needs a unique code. 
I decided to go with the date and Serial Number of a device because there will never be the same device being submitted on the same day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you concatenate these two fields into a new 3rd field, you need to add the values together...

```
$("input[name='ID_field']").val($("input[name='Date_field']").val() + $("input[name='Other-value_field']").val());
```

If the date is being generated dynamically...

```
var d = new Date();
$("input[name='ID_field']").val(d.getTime() + $("input[name='Other-value_field']").val());
```

Comment: Thanks so much!
Took me a while to figure out where exactly I needed to put it but it works!